# Updating Navigator component depending on state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, navigator

Say i have two sub components, Login and Profile. Login is rendered by default via Navigator

```
<Navigator initialRoute={{name: 'login'}} renderScene={this.renderScene} />
```

heres my renderScene method

```
renderScene(route) {
    switch (route) {
        case 'login':
            return <Login / >;

        case 'profile':
            return <Profile / >;
    }
}
```

So when someone sign in via Login, the state is updated and everything (the main app container that holds the Navigator) gets re-rendered. So when and where do I actually push the Profile route to the navigator?

Do i change the initial route depending on the state in the renderScene method?

Or do i push the new route after the re-render ?

Or should i be using shouldComponentUpdate and not re-render but push the new route to the nav, depending on the state.

Comment: You need to update your question with more code samples. Usually you would do this in an onClick handler in the `<Navigator/>` component. When the user clicks on the link call an action creator `dispatch(changeRoute('login'));` or when the user logs in `dispatch(login('user', 'pass'));`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, i dont have a problem with dispatching actions, or reading the state at all. My question is about changing the initialRoute of the navigator depending on the state. 

This initialRoute initially is Login, so Navigator renders the Login page, however after i've logged in and the new state is passed in, this will re-render Navigator and here i've tried changing the initialRoute to something else, and while my function does display the change, the renderScene method still reads Login. I also tried using InitialRouteStack and splicing out Login but still same result.

Comment: Please add some more code; there's not enough to figure out where the problem lies. It sounds like you need to `connect()` a component to access state in `mapStateToProps` to get the initialRoute.

Comment: My issue is not with redux or its architecture, i already have connect. I will try update my question with more code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of Redux and maintain the state of the authenticated session like so,

`const initialState = {
  session: {
    isAuthenticated: getToken() ? true : false
  }
}`

Here `getToken` can be the method that fetches the access token. Typically, you store this in local storage when the server authenticates the log in and responds with success.

Since you have already connected the component to the store using `[connect()][1]`, you now have access to the state as `this.props` and you can now do the following in your `renderScene` method.

`renderScene(route, navigator) {
  const { session } = this.props
  route = session.isAuthenticated
            ? { id: 'login' }
            : { id: 'profile' }
  switch (route.id) {
  case 'login':
    // Return the login component
  case 'profile':
    // Return the profile component
  default:
    // Return default component
  }
}`

With this you don't really have to push since the state change triggers the re-render. You can add more logic here as per your need but hope this can get you started, if you haven't already figured this out.